# How to print arguments from a known element until an unknown element of an array with Bash

Tags: bash, array

I am having a blonde moment.

This is my data from `myfile.csv`

```
1429829254,e,SE,StckXchg,HDCU3000623,d,scan,253,47968,94,1420824420,JSSE-213,199,BS,KIT,*OUT*
1429897704,e,SE,StckXchg,HDCU3000623,d,scan,253,68496104,103,1420923818,SP-TMX6BP-101-112Z,*OUT*
1429897718,e,SE,StckXchg,HDCU3000623,d,scan,253,68510090,104,1420923832,02132,*OUT*
1429897767,e,SE,StckXchg,HDCU3000623,d,scan,253,68559085,105,1420923878,02132,*OUT*
1429912759,e,SE,StckXchg,HDCU3000623,d,scan,255,47966,107,1420924040,JSF-1,4"MEG0004,*OUT*
1429912766,e,SE,StckXchg,HDCU3000623,d,scan,255,54955,108,1420924047,02134,*OUT*
1429982863,e,SE,StckXchg,HDCU3000623,d,scan,256,47965,120,1420987942,JSDL-JA120901S,*OUT*
1429982870,e,SE,StckXchg,HDCU3000623,d,scan,256,54953,121,1420987961,02132,*OUT*
1429982877,e,SE,StckXchg,HDCU3000623,d,scan,256,61954,109,1420971277,02134,*OUT*
```

I currently put this data into an array and extract each of the elements individually.

But our input data has changed and now there the elements with a line can vary- and can vary by a lot. I was curious to know how I can extract data from the above sample, from the 12th element up until the last element.

With my code this is what I do:

```
cat $out_file_name |  while read line
do
    awk_var=`echo "$line" | awk -F"," '{print $1, $5, $10, $12, $13, $14}'`         #Get the appropriate arguments
    awk_var_array=($awk_var)

    timestamp=${awk_var_array[0]}
    container==${awk_var_array[1]}
    scan_id=${awk_var_array[2]}
    part_no=${awk_var_array[3]}
    direction=${awk_var_array[4]}

    #further processing and send the above to a mysql table
done
```

but now this obviously doesn't work. So I need to find a way of storing all the element from the 12th element till the last element (in/out).

would it be done with a for loop? Something like this perhaps?

```
for element_count in $(seq 13 $({#awk_var_array[@]}-1))
do
    var_name=my_var_''$element_count
    $var_name=${awk_var_array[element_count]
done
```

Comment: It would help to see the loop you have around your posted code, and whether (as it seems) you throw away the first line of data while processing the second line, etc. - I suppose you might want something like: `while IFS=, read timestamp x x x container x x x x scan_id x part_no direction rest ; do ...some_processing... ; done < file.csv`.

Comment: @Janis, Could you elaborate? I'm a strong programmer -.- !

Comment: Your code seems to have a loop that you did not post; how else would "$line" be else retrieved from your csv file? - So you'd not need all that `echo`, pipes, `awk`, arrays, etc.; rather just a loop over the csv file entries and a `read` to "unique identifiers" for your processing. The code would get quite simple and performant. - But to be sure that would require that you post the surrounding loop code (how you read the csv file) and explain the further processing of your variables (it doesn't seem you need them stored in arrays). - Note: the 'x' in my code are ignored fields.

Comment: I just did - it's a `while read line` from a csv file. I process the data - concatenate some identifiers then shoot it off over to a mysql table...

Comment: Okay, so my assumption seems to have been correct. I posted an answer based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bash` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `${parameter:offset:length}` form with array:

```
$ array=($(seq 20))
$ printf "%s " "${a[@]: -12}"
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Perfect! But how can I assign a unique identifier to each of the values?

Comment: @3kstc: I'm not sure what do you mean unique identifier here? You can store that sub array into another array for manipulation. Or you can get each element starting from 12th element. Example `${a[@]: -12:1}` will get the 12th element, `${a[@]: -12:2}` will get the 13th element and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the further information we got from the various comments, I think all you need is this code:

```
while IFS=, read timestamp x x x container x x x x scan_id x part_no direction rest
do
   # compose SQL command using "${timestamp}" "${container}" ... "${direction}" "${rest}" and send it to mysql database
done < "${out_file_name}"
```

Note: The `x` in the read command represent dummy fields that will be skipped (and not assigned an own unique identifier), and the variable `rest` contains all the fields in one variable beyond the ones explicitly enumerated in the `read` argument list.

Comment: Thanks Janis - one last question - how would I modify the code if  I wanted to get for example from `part_no` field all the way to the `n-1`th field  and than also the `n`th field. Where n is the total number of fileds

Comment: @3kst; You mean you are **not** interested in details of `part_no` and subsequent fields, and it suffices for you to have them collected all in one variable? - Then reduce the `read` variable list: `read timestamp x x x container x x x x scan_id x rest`. - The point is; increase the list with as many variables as you are interested to distingush individually, and subsume the rest in a final variable `rest`. If there are less fields in the data than the `read` command has then the respective fields will just be blank, if there are more fields, the remaining are in the final variable; no harm.